# Data Slicer for Differential Manchester

Tags: operational-amplifier, modulation

I have a differential manchester data stream (**channel1**) in the form of packets. I'm showing a capture of one packet. All packets begin with a stream of 1's. This is key, as per [Maxim application note 3671](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3671.html): "

> This circuit functions well when the received data stream has enough
>   extra bits at the beginning of a packet or frame (in the form of a
>   preamble or synch pattern) that it can afford to lose while the R1-C4
>   circuit charges up to the correct slicing threshold.

It is then suggested a fundamental [data slicer](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-decode-manchester-encoded-data-using-hardware/) can decode manchester encoded signals.

I need to convert this to to something an arduino, etc.  can work with. 
[image: scope output]

So I built the data slicer and tried various R and C value. I get a waveform as shown in **channel 0**. I need to obviously change my circuit, but will the fundamental circuit even get the job done?

[image: circuit diagram]

**Other Information:**

This is a follow up to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476481/hardware-software-needed-to-decode-differential-manchester). This [user](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17574/tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75) stated in a comment:

> It is trivial to make a Manchester decoder from simple logic and 3/4 1shot.

I think he is referring to a "one-shot multivibrator op-amp circuit", with specific voltage cut-offs?

**UPDATE**
[This FCC filing](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/UCS86120691/2539857) shows the schematic for reading and writing the DeLaval Alcom bus. I have reproduced my version below minus the protection portion.
[image: Alcom receive circuit]

Comment: Data slicers do actually work and so what is your real question?

Comment: Recognize that the *data slicer* as shown in the OP schematic, and a *Manchester decoder* should likely be considered as **two separate circuits**, and not combined. Using a LM358 opamp as data comparator isn't recommended - a LM393 might substitute. You also might consider shortening **R1C1** time constant somewhat...is there a reason for waiting about a second for it to settle before good data gets sliced?

Comment: very useful comment glen_geek. I changed the RC time to something more reasonable, I was that far off the rails because I was working through different RC values to try and get some change in the output. Basically the op-amp is the problem. I have ordered a LM2903N and will try it with that.

Comment: This demonstrates not only the comparator is unnecessary as all you need is a simple self-biased logic inverter and the   "simple" 3/4T one-shot clock recovery solution http://tinyurl.com/rzqka9w  which I indicated in my previous answer. but is in fact a demo of transmitting random data in bi-phase then decoding it and comparing them.

Comment: Tony, That link is very clear. I wish I had of had that link in the previous question. The link shows the best solution with clock recovery.  I don't understand "the comparator is unnecessary", are you saying that the fundamental data slicer solution will not work to get a basic output? I agree it  is inferior to 3/4T one-shot clock recovery.

Comment: There are many good ways to limit analog data which does not demand that it be a comparator. Causing excessive startup time is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The articles talk about a comparator. LM358 is an op-amp, not a comparator. In general, op-amps work extremely poorly as comparators.

Comment: The op-amp is the reason for the poor output. A LM2903N comparator has been ordered and should work. The RC values will be changed as well to something on the timescale of micro seconds. As per calculator: (https://www.digikey.ca/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-time-constant)

Comment: This is neither the problem nor does it state a solution.  The real problem is the RC duration is >>>T= 1/bit rate when it should be around 15~20T.

Answer (score 1):

that --- 1Meg Ohm and 100 uf --- is a 100 second time constant.

Also the (Ibias * 1Meg Ohm) may not been suitable.