# Send differential Manchester encoding over Ethernet

Tags: arduino, ethernet, manchester-coding

For our feed system we have a process computer and feeding boxes in the stable. They are connected with a two-wire cable. Somebody else in this forum found out that it is differential Manchester encoding.

See these links: [Hardware/software needed to decode Differential Manchester?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476481/hardware-software-needed-to-decode-differential-manchester) and [Data Slicer for Differential Manchester](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478483/data-slicer-for-differential-manchester)

I have exactly the same system as in this thread. What I want is: send the signal over Ethernet to another location, pick up  the signal there, and place a feed box. The signal needs to communicate 2 ways.

Is this possible and how? Can I do it with Arduinos with Ethernet shields? Or is it more complicated?

I have two devices that can send CANBUS over Ethernet. But then I found it isn't CANBUS and found the thread in the link.

Comment: What is a "stabe"? What is a "somebode"? Please proofread your post and edit it to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: @ThePhoton Stable, as in horses, or rather, horses, as in stables. (sorry, could not resist)

Comment: @ThePhoton  Yes you are right! Sorry for that. I had to much hurry and English is not my main language.

Comment: It is a cow stable. The cows have a transponder on their neck. If they are going in a box, the cow is recognized by the transponder the computer knows if she wil get some feed or she have all eaten allready. And the communication between the boxes in the stable and de computer in the office is a two wire bus cable. They call it the Alcom bus. But as in the first post the other user find out that it will be diffrential Manchester encoding. Its is for me not necesary to translate the messages but can I send through ethernet and pick it up somewhere else and use it?

Comment: See - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476121/decoding-an-unknown-serial-bitstream-that-does-not-fit-8-n-1

Comment: Weird English language usage thing: cows are housed in byres.  Horses are housed in stables.  But we're happy to stick with "stable" here.  Or just use "barn", which also applies to both, sort of.

Comment: Just to clarify here: you are _not_ asking whether you can use Cat-5 cabling (i.e. "Ethernet cable") instead of your existing two-wire cable.  You're asking if you can have a box in the barn that's two-wire in and Ethernet out, and a box somewhere else that's Ethernet in and two-wire out -- yes?  So, sort of an Ethernet-enabled cable extender?  If so, please *edit your question* with this clarification.

Comment: I forgot.. Is the Ethernet PHY not doing Manchester encoding already? The very begining of Ethernet MAC + PHY took 2 cards of STD boards, and had that Manchester encoding somewhere, I thought.

Comment: ethernet has 8 conductors and you only need two, so yes it should be possible to just use ethernet wire to connect the two locations.  if you want to pass the signals over a LAN then it becomes more complicated.

Comment: @jay - The ethernet PHY is working at 10, 100, 1000Mbps and not easily usable at other frequencies.

Comment: @KevinWhite, thanks, I understand. If the microprocessor cannot handle encoding, then CPLD/FPGA would be the solution.

Comment: Yes oke Byres, I never heard off that word :) I will use Barn.
The problem is, the barn where I will go on with the feedsystem is 10 km away. We have internet connection in both barns. The speed off the bus is 62500kb as in the thread off the other user find out.